# link_to get rails error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, view-helpers

I am using a simple `link_to` which we use always in my rails app but it is giving this error.

`wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

My code in view.

```
<%= link_to category.name store_path %>
```

The path is correct when running in the url and also in the console.

```
2.2.3 :003 > app.store_path
=> "/store"
```

I don't understand why this picking up an argument over here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are missing `,`
`<%= link_to category.name, store_path %>`

Comment: Oops that was a typo...thanks i was in too much hurry actually!